# How display price in ml in Stripe API Checkout?

Tags: stripe-payments

With Stripe API Checkout, does anyone know how to change what I underlined ?

**I need to display a price in ml**. *Example: I must write /100 ml and not /piece*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value isn't customizable. I think the best way to handle this is to add the size to the product name, "Le Baume (100ml)".